# SQL Addition of two Temp Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, addition

I have two temp tables that are counting a number of IDs.  I want to combine those tables to give the count for each and then add those together.  This is what I have so far.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#order') is not null drop table #order 
select count (a.patientSID) as 'Order Count'

into #order
from CPRSOrder.CPRSOrder a
join sstaff.SStaff b on b.staffSID = a.EnteredbyStaffSID 
join spatient.spatient c on c.patientSID = a.patientSID
where b.staffName = xxxxxxxx
and a.enteredDateTime >= '20180801' and a.enteredDateTime <= '20180828'

if object_id('tempdb..#note') is not null drop table #note 
select count (a.patientSID) as 'Note Count'

into #note
from tiu.tiudocument a
join sstaff.SStaff b on b.staffSID = a.EnteredbyStaffSID 
--join spatient.spatient c on c.patientSID = a.patientSID
where b.staffName = xxxxxxxx
and a.episodeBeginDateTime >= '20180801' and a.episodeBeginDateTime     <= '20180828'

select (select [Note Count] from #note) as 'Note Count',
(select [Order Count] from #order) as 'Order Count',
sum((select [Order Count] from #order) + (select [Note Count] from #note))  as Total
```

Comment: It looks like this is for SQL Server. I added the tag for you. Please correct, if my assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `sum()`, unless you want to aggregate. Also, since the tables contain only one row each, this could be simplified a little by using a cross join.

```
SELECT n.[Note Count],
       o.[Order Count],
       n.[Note Count] + o.[Order Count] [Total]
       FROM #note n
            CROSS JOIN #order o;
```

Comment: Is there a way to mark this as the answer.  Thank you.  I was getting an aggregate error, which is what I didn't want.

Comment: @pbrt: Welcome. There should be a check mark on the left of the answer. If you click that and it turns green, that means you have marked it as accepted answer.

Comment: There's a check button you need to click

Answer (score 0):

While there's nothing syntactically wrong with selecting a single column from a temp table, what is clear is you are using an entire temp table to save a single value, an aggregated sum.  An integer variable can also hold a count.  For example:

```
DECLARE @order int = 
( 
   select count (a.patientSID) 
     from CPRSOrder.CPRSOrder a
     join sstaff.SStaff b on b.staffSID = a.EnteredbyStaffSID 
     join spatient.spatient c on c.patientSID = a.patientSID
    where b.staffName = xxxxxxxx
      and a.enteredDateTime >= '20180801' and a.enteredDateTime <= '20180828'
)

DECLARE @note int = ( 
  select count (a.patientSID) 
    from tiu.tiudocument a
    join sstaff.SStaff b on b.staffSID = a.EnteredbyStaffSID 
  --join spatient.spatient c on c.patientSID = a.patientSID
   where b.staffName = xxxxxxxx
     and a.episodeBeginDateTime >= '20180801' and a.episodeBeginDateTime     <= '20180828'
)

SELECT @note AS [note count]
      ,@order AS [order count]
      ,@order + @note AS [total]
```

Comment: Both of these ways are correct.  The integer route did seem to slow the query down just a little with our database.  Sticky Bit's response ran in under 3 secs and Zorkolot's ran in 24 secs.  But thank you both for your response.

Comment: @pbrt that's very surprising. I'm not sure what you did but it shouldn't have taken 8 times longer.